# Send a string from dart file to a kotlin file that is being used inside a package in my flutter project

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

is it possible to send a string from dart file to a kotlin file thats inside a third party package that is being used on my flutter project?
so the structure is like this

/Users/ritesh/Documents/my-flutter-project-name/lib/screens/dashboard_screen.dart
/Users/ritesh/Documents/my-flutter-project-name/ios/.symlinks/plugins/background_locator_2/android/src/main/kotlin/yukams/app/background_locator_2/IsolateHolderService.kt

I want to send a username from dashboard.dart to IsolateHolderService.kt

The code is like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DashboardScreen> createState() => _DashboardScreenState();
}

class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  String username = 'user089'; **//how do i send this to the IsolateHolderService.kt**
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container();
  }
}
```

```
package yukams.app.background_locator_2

import android.app.*
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.PowerManager
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import io.flutter.FlutterInjector
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import yukams.app.background_locator_2.pluggables.DisposePluggable
import yukams.app.background_locator_2.pluggables.InitPluggable
import yukams.app.background_locator_2.pluggables.Pluggable
import yukams.app.background_locator_2.provider.*
import java.util.HashMap
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat

class IsolateHolderService : MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler, LocationUpdateListener, Service() {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val ACTION_SHUTDOWN = "SHUTDOWN"

        @JvmStatic
        val ACTION_START = "START"

        @JvmStatic
        val ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION = "UPDATE_NOTIFICATION"

        @JvmStatic
        private val WAKELOCK_TAG = "IsolateHolderService::WAKE_LOCK"

        @JvmStatic
        var backgroundEngine: FlutterEngine? = null

        @JvmStatic
        private val notificationId = 1

        @JvmStatic
        var isServiceRunning = false

        @JvmStatic
        var isServiceInitialized = false

        fun getBinaryMessenger(context: Context?): BinaryMessenger? {
            val messenger = backgroundEngine?.dartExecutor?.binaryMessenger
            return messenger
                ?: if (context != null) {
                    backgroundEngine = FlutterEngine(context)
                    backgroundEngine?.dartExecutor?.binaryMessenger
                }else{
                    messenger
                }
        }
    }

    private var notificationChannelName = "Flutter Locator Plugin"
    private var notificationTitle = "Start Location Tracking"
    private var notificationMsg = "Track location in background"
    private var notificationBigMsg =
        "Background location is on to keep the app up-tp-date with your location. This is required for main features to work properly when the app is not running."
    private var notificationIconColor = 0
    private var icon = 0
    private var wakeLockTime = 60 * 60 * 1000L // 1 hour default wake lock time
    private var locatorClient: BLLocationProvider? = null
    internal lateinit var backgroundChannel: MethodChannel
    internal var context: Context? = null
    private var pluggables: ArrayList<Pluggable> = ArrayList()

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startLocatorService(this)
        startForeground(notificationId, getNotification())
    }

    private fun start() {
        (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
            newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, WAKELOCK_TAG).apply {
                setReferenceCounted(false)
                acquire(wakeLockTime)
            }
        }

        // Starting Service as foreground with a notification prevent service from closing
        val notification = getNotification()
        startForeground(notificationId, notification)

        pluggables.forEach {
            context?.let { it1 -> it.onServiceStart(it1) }
        }
    }

    private fun getNotification(): Notification {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // Notification channel is available in Android O and up
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                Keys.CHANNEL_ID, notificationChannelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            )

            (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager)
                .createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, getMainActivityClass(this))
        intent.action = Keys.NOTIFICATION_ACTION

        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Keys.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setContentText(notificationMsg)
            .setStyle(
                NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(notificationBigMsg)
            )
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setColor(notificationIconColor)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true) // so when data is updated don't make sound and alert in android 8.0+
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.e("IsolateHolderService", "onStartCommand => intent.action : ${intent?.action}")
        if(intent == null) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.e("IsolateHolderService", "app has crashed, stopping it")
                stopSelf()
            }
            else {
                return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
            }
        }

        when {
            ACTION_SHUTDOWN == intent?.action -> {
                isServiceRunning = false
                shutdownHolderService()
            }
            ACTION_START == intent?.action -> {
                if (isServiceRunning) {
                    isServiceRunning = false
                    shutdownHolderService()
                }

                if (!isServiceRunning) {
                    isServiceRunning = true
                    startHolderService(intent)
                }
            }
            ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION == intent?.action -> {
                if (isServiceRunning) {
                    updateNotification(intent)
                }
            }
        }

        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun startHolderService(intent: Intent) {
        Log.e("IsolateHolderService", "startHolderService")
        notificationChannelName =
            intent.getStringExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME).toString()
        notificationTitle =
            intent.getStringExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_TITLE).toString()
        notificationMsg = intent.getStringExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_MSG).toString()
        notificationBigMsg =
            intent.getStringExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_BIG_MSG).toString()
        val iconNameDefault = "ic_launcher"
        var iconName = intent.getStringExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_ICON)
        if (iconName == null || iconName.isEmpty()) {
            iconName = iconNameDefault
        }
        icon = resources.getIdentifier(iconName, "mipmap", packageName)
        notificationIconColor =
            intent.getLongExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_ICON_COLOR, 0).toInt()
        wakeLockTime = intent.getIntExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_WAKE_LOCK_TIME, 60) * 60 * 1000L

        locatorClient = context?.let { getLocationClient(it) }
        locatorClient?.requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(intent))

        // Fill pluggable list
        if (intent.hasExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_INIT_PLUGGABLE)) {
            pluggables.add(InitPluggable())
        }

        if (intent.hasExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_DISPOSABLE_PLUGGABLE)) {
            pluggables.add(DisposePluggable())
        }

        start()
    }

    private fun shutdownHolderService() {
        Log.e("IsolateHolderService", "shutdownHolderService")
        (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
            newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, WAKELOCK_TAG).apply {
                if (isHeld) {
                    release()
                }
            }
        }

        locatorClient?.removeLocationUpdates()
        stopForeground(true)
        stopSelf()

        pluggables.forEach {
            context?.let { it1 -> it.onServiceDispose(it1) }
        }
    }

    private fun updateNotification(intent: Intent) {
        Log.e("IsolateHolderService", "updateNotification")
        if (intent.hasExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_TITLE)) {
            notificationTitle =
                intent.getStringExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_TITLE).toString()
        }

        if (intent.hasExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_MSG)) {
            notificationMsg =
                intent.getStringExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_MSG).toString()
        }

        if (intent.hasExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_BIG_MSG)) {
            notificationBigMsg =
                intent.getStringExtra(Keys.SETTINGS_ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_BIG_MSG).toString()
        }

        val notification = getNotification()
        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
    }

    private fun getMainActivityClass(context: Context): Class<*>? {
        val packageName = context.packageName
        val launchIntent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
        val className = launchIntent?.component?.className ?: return null

        return try {
            Class.forName(className)
        } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }

    override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        try {
            when (call.method) {
                Keys.METHOD_SERVICE_INITIALIZED -> {
                    isServiceRunning = true
                }
                else -> result.notImplemented()
            }

            result.success(null)
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }


    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        isServiceRunning = false
        super.onDestroy()
    }


    private fun getLocationClient(context: Context): BLLocationProvider {
        return when (PreferencesManager.getLocationClient(context)) {
            LocationClient.Google -> GoogleLocationProviderClient(context, this)
            LocationClient.Android -> AndroidLocationProviderClient(context, this)
        }
    }

    override fun onLocationUpdated(location: HashMap<Any, Any>?) {
        try {
            context?.let {
                FlutterInjector.instance().flutterLoader().ensureInitializationComplete(
                    it, null
                )
            }

            //https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1641
            //https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36059
            //https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1641/commits/4358fbba3327f1fa75bc40df503ca5341fdbb77d
            // new version of flutter can not invoke method from background thread
            if (location != null) {
                val callback =
                    context?.let {
                        PreferencesManager.getCallbackHandle(
                            it,
                            Keys.CALLBACK_HANDLE_KEY
                        )
                    } as Long

                val result: HashMap<Any, Any> =
                    hashMapOf(
                        Keys.ARG_CALLBACK to callback,
                        Keys.ARG_LOCATION to location
                    )

                sendLocationEvent(result)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }
    }

    private fun sendLocationEvent(result: HashMap<Any, Any>) {
        //https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1641
        //https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36059
        //https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1641/commits/4358fbba3327f1fa75bc40df503ca5341fdbb77d
        // new version of flutter can not invoke method from background thread

        if (backgroundEngine != null) {
            context?.let {
                val backgroundChannel =
                    MethodChannel(
                        getBinaryMessenger(it)!!,
                        Keys.BACKGROUND_CHANNEL_ID
                    )
                Handler(it.mainLooper)
                    .post {
                        Log.d("plugin", "seandLocationEvent $result") **//i want to use the username here**
                        backgroundChannel.invokeMethod(Keys.BCM_SEND_LOCATION, result)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```